# Can CMD/CTRL+Shift+1-9 be captured in browser js?

Tags: javascript, event-handling, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-events

I'm building an SPA where it would be quite useful if I could capture the shortcuts <kbd>cmd</kbd>/<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> through 9. It appears to me that this *should* be possible, since no browser I know binds these keys to anything else, but for some reason, pressing <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> (I'm using a macbook) fails to even cause a keyboard event.

Is this an inherent limitation of Chrome, or is there some special thing that I don't know of that needs to be done to capture these events?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have a macbook, but I can capture <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> (be sure to give focus to the snippet results frame):

```js
document.body.addEventListener('keyup', function(e)
{
  if((e.code == 'Digit1' || e.code == 'Numpad1') && e.ctrlKey && e.shiftKey)
  {
    console.log('ctrl+shift+1');
  }
  else
  {
    console.log(e.key, 'pressed')
  }
});
```

This is layout dependent, i.e. if you are not using QWERTY, beware! See the [`KeyboardEvent` page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent) for help with different keyboard layouts.

Comment: Thanks! I can capture CTRL+1-9 too, but for some reason CMD+1-9 (which should be bound the same way as CTRL+1-9 on non-OSX systems) doesn't fire an event. I guess i'll just use CTRL as the modifier, independent of the platform, then.

Comment: You need to check `metaKey` for command

Comment: I know. But I can't, because it just outright refuses to even cause an event for me to check anything on. Pressing CMD+1 just does... nothing